# Jquery slider with interval speeds up when screen resolution changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

so my slider works perfectly fine; switching evey 3 seconds and stopping when i mouse over it or if i click arrows. then it restarts if i leave it alone.

all works fine.

however, when i change resolution to work on responsiveness is starts speeding up and doesnt respond to the mouseover stop.

```
$var main = function(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();

    });


$('.arrow-next').click(function(){
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    if(nextSlide.length == 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        };
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();
    if(nextDot.length == 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        };
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });
};

$('.arrow-prev').click(function(){
    currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
    if(prevSlide.length == 0){
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        };
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();
    if(prevDot.length == 0){
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        };
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');


    });


$(document).ready(main);

$(document).ready( function() {

var auto = setInterval(function() {

  var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    if(nextSlide.length == 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        };
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();
    if(nextDot.length == 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        };
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
}, 3000);


 $('.slider, .arrow-prev, .arrow-next').mouseover(function(){
clearInterval(auto);
}).mouseout(function(){
var auto = setInterval(function() {

  var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    if(nextSlide.length == 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        };
    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();
    if(nextDot.length == 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        };
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
}, 3000);
})

});
```

Comment: I figured it out... since I declared "var" inside function it was a not global variable and so it stacked. Now i added var auto outside the function and removed var inside functions and it works perfectly with resize; minimize, and everything :D

Comment: You do not need a semi-colon after conditional bracket:  `if(conditional){
       ...code...
        };` it should only be  `if(conditional){
       ...code...
        }` and note that `$var main = ` is a syntax error (likely a code post issue)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... since I declared "var" inside function it was a not global variable and so it stacked. Now i added var auto outside the function and removed var inside functions and it works perfectly with resize; minimize, and everything :D

i started looking at js and jquery about 3 weeks ago and had 0 knowledge prior so my code may be...how to say it...le crap! but at least I am happy I figured this one out!

I welcome advice in general about this slider.